# Shutter Select Button Greyed out - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, shutter

I've installed shutter via the snap package installer and apt install... the snap installed version will not start.  The apt install version has the select button greyed out.

Any ideas?
Wayne

Answer (score 1):

Are you possibly using Wayland? If so, this is expected, the Wayland support is only rudimentary, that is, only allows full screen capture so far: https://github.com/shutter-project/shutter/issues/187 The only workaround to restore the full functionality is to switch to Xorg.